# Change category meta title and meta discription

Tags: magento-1.7

A lot of different people filled the the category's of magento, at the moment we have a lot of difference phrases in the meta discription of meta title.

I have written a script that update the category, but none of it worked.

Option 1:

```
            $_category->setMetaTitle($general['meta_title']);
            $_category->setMetaDescription($general['meta_description']);
```

Option 2:

```
        $_category->setData(array(
            'meta_title'    => $general['meta_title'],
            'meta_discription'  => $general['meta_description']
        ));
```

Ofcourse started and end with :

```
      $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
       $_category->save();
```

Any ideas how i can update a category programmatically ?

As requested complete script:

```
<?php
 ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");
 set_time_limit(0);
 require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(8);

$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

 if (count($_categories) > 0):
foreach($_categories as $_category):
echo $_category->getName();
    echo "\n";

    $general['meta_title'] = trim($_category->getName()).' kopen? Bestel online bij Wortel'; //Page title
                    $general['meta_description'] = "Koop '.trim($_category->getName()).' bij Wortel. .
                            Het juiste advies voor '.trim($_category->getName()).'. Wortel maakt blij.";


                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());


                $_category->setMetaTitle($general['meta_title']);
                $_category->setMetaDescription($general['meta_description']);
        /*
                 $_category->setData(array(
                    'meta_title'    => $general['meta_title'],
                    'meta_discription'  => $general['meta_description']
                ));
*/
               $_category->save();

            // getMetaTitle

            $check = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getMetaTitle();
        echo $check;
        echo "\n";

        endforeach;
 endif;
```

Comment: can you post the whole script and can you define how you ascertained it didn't work.

Comment: First of all don't use `setData(array)`. Use `addData(array)`. Are you trying to change the values for a specific store view or for default settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the load on the database and the server you might want to prevent loading the whole category. Haven't tested this but it should work

```
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");
set_time_limit(0);
require 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(8)
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'));


if ($_collection->getSize()):
   foreach($_collection as $_category):

      $_category->setMetaTitle(trim($_category->getName()).' kopen? Bestel online bij Wortel');
      $_category->setMetaDescription("Koop ".trim($_category->getName())." bij Wortel. Het juiste advies voor ".trim($_category->getName()).". Wortel maakt blij.");
      $_category->getResource()->saveAttribute($_category, 'meta_title');
      $_category->getResource()->saveAttribute($_category, 'meta_description');

   endforeach;
 endif;
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::saveAttribute() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wortel/erik.php on line 26

Comment: Please turn of the flat category data and try again

Comment: Yeah! Great :) with flat off it works.

Comment: @SanderMangel I have changed category meta title, after I paste my category URL to Facebook, here the old meta tile will get and display, many i know how many days taken to update my category meta title tag updates.